# jQuery addClass to list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple pages that all use a simple tab menu at the top.
The menu (aka list) is stored in a separate html file:

```
<ul>
  <li id="Tab1"><a href='../Page1.html'> Page1 </a></li>
  <li id="Tab2"><a href='../Page2.html'> Page2 </a></li>
  <li id="Tab3"><a href='../Page3.html'> Page3 </a></li>
```

every page has `<div id='tabs'> </div>` and

```
$('#tabs').load('CommonTabs.html');
```

Everything works fine, my tabs load into the 'tabs' div. Now I want to set a class of one div on each page to "active", so that the proper style defined in a css can be applied.
I tried:

```
$('#tabs').load('CommonTabs.html');
$('#Tab1'.addClass("active");
```

But that doesn't seem to work. When I do "inspect element" in a browser, the li does not have the "active" class assigned.

Comment: `$('#Tab1'.addClass("active");` should be `$('#Tab1').addClass("active");`

Comment: After fixing the typo mentioned above, make sure the `CommonTabs.html` is loaded before trying to manipulate its `DOM` elements. `.load()` is an asynchronous call.

Comment: Sorry about the typo, that was just in the post, not in my code.
@MelanciaUK, how do I ensure that the html is loaded before manipulating it? I think that is my problem, because when I added that HTML block directly in the page, the jQuery part works correctly.

Comment: Check @AlexisKing answer below.

Answer (score 12):

The `load` function is asynchronous, so the data is not loaded when the second call executes. Perform it in a callback function instead:

```
$('#tabs').load('CommonTabs.html', function () {
    $('#Tab1').addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error. Try:
`$('#Tab1').addClass("active");`

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an example to set a class to a specific element on a button click. Of course you will need to create a button with the class addClassButtonTab3 for this to work.

```
$('.addClassButtonTab3').click('on', function() {
    $('#tab3').addClass('active');
});
```

We are binding an event handler to a button with class 'addClassButtonTab3' and when it is clicked we are adding a class to an element with ID tab3.